# how can I apply a key from/to with transform : translate from where is located an element to position determinate?

Tags: css-animations

i would like to use css-animation with a keyframes with translateX, and

I want to set the 100% value of translateX to 0 and the value of 0% of translateX to whatever position the element is currently. I dont want to have a determinate value for the 0%, 
how can i achieve that ? 
thanks

```
@keyframes moduleNumberKeyLeave{
  from{ transform: translateX( actual position)}
  to{ transform : translateX(0)}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@keyframes moduleNumberKeyLeave{
  from{ transform: translateX(none)}
  to{ transform : translateX(50px)}
}
```